# How to change permission of a file created using UTL_FILE.FOPEN?

Tags: sql, oracle, file-permissions

I have an oracle procedure which creates a text file using the UTL_FILE.FOPEN function. The file is created with permission 660. How can I change the permission of the file without using chmod?(I don't have access to the server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the umask of the Unix user that owns the Oracle process (resp. ask the system administrator to perform this task for your), see

[UTL_FILE permissions](http://jenniferlinca.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/using-utl_file-how-file-permissions-are-determined-working-sample/)